# How to play streaming audio with QMediaPlayer?

Tags: c++, qt, audio-streaming, qtmultimedia, qmediaplayer

I have audio stream from server that I want to play with `QMediaPlayer` in my program. Everything works when I first download file to `QBuffer` and then call `setMedia` and `play` method from the player. But if I want to play music while stream is still working, media player only plays sound to the position when `setMedia` method was called and then stoppes. 
Is there any possible ways to make it work like I want to? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to construct `QMediaPlayer` with `QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback` option like : `QMediaPlayer * player = new QMediaPlayer(0,QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback)` ?

Comment: I tried it and it still plays only till the position when `setMedia` was called.

Comment: When you are asking, why some code does not work, it's good idea to attach the code... At least a good, relevant snippet, if not a complete [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason for it not to work, if you are initializing the player in the right way.

Since you haven't shared the code you have written (also since I won't be available for the rest of the day to see your response if I leave a comment), I will leave some sample code here.
See if the code below works for you.

```
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer(this, QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback);
player->setMedia(QUrl("http://vpr.streamguys.net/vpr64.mp3"));
player->setVolume(80);
player->play();
```

If it does, try the same by changing the url to your stream.

EDIT: I am assuming that the player is exhausting the buffer before you update it. Try keeping an eye on the `bufferStatus` and `QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus`.
I quote from the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html):

```
bufferStatus : const int
```

`This property holds the percentage of the temporary buffer filled before playback begins or resumes, from (empty) to (full).
When the player object is buffering; this property holds the percentage of the temporary buffer that is filled. The buffer will need to reach 100% filled before playback can start or resume, at which time mediaStatus() will return BufferedMedia or BufferingMedia. If the value is anything lower than 100, mediaStatus() will return StalledMedia.`

Comment: Yes. That's what it looks like. See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404500/qmediaplayer-streaming-from-a-custom-qiodevice-with-encryption-on-mac-os-10-9) post is of any help to you.

Comment: I am not sure if this will make any difference. But try passing an `QMediaContent` instance as the first parameter to `QMediaPlayer::setMedia` instead of `NULL`. i.e.,
`mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(), song);`

Comment: That might be a possible explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Via QAudioOutput:

```
    QByteArray* yourSoundData = blah blah...;
    QBuffer* buffer = new QBuffer;
    buffer->setData(yourSoundData);
    buffer->open(QBuffer::ReadOnly);

    QAudioFormat format; // According to your sound format (e.g. wav)
    format.setSampleRate(22050);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(16);
    format.setCodec("audio/wav");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

    QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
    if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
        qWarning() << "Raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play audio.";
        return;
    }

    QAudioOutput* audio = new QAudioOutput(format, this);
    audio->start(buffer);
```

More info: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiooutput.html