# How to stream sound on MAC OS using QT?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, audio, streaming

I want to develop an application to play sounds from web radio streams.

I first did it using the following code :

```
mRequest.setUrl(QUrl(QString("http://dummy.com/file.mp3")));
mPlayer.setMedia(mRequest);
mPlayer.play();
```

It works fine but I want to do it passing a custom QIODevice because I have to process the stream in a specific way before playing it.

I found some example describing how to do that but it seems not to work.

I then found an interesting link here describing an issue with streaming on MAC OS using Qt ([QMediaplayer streaming from a custom QIODevice with encryption on Mac OS (10.9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404500/qmediaplayer-streaming-from-a-custom-qiodevice-with-encryption-on-mac-os-10-9)) and what seems to explain the problem ([Supported media player features](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Multimedia_Backends)).

So, assuming I want to get a stream from a web radio, process specific received bytes before playing, what QT class do you advice me to use ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Considering that the documentation clearly states that there is no "Stream Source" support for MacOS, you may just have to write your own Qt classes. But you would have to implement your desired functionality by yourself which could be a lot of work. You may be better off looking for a third party library that provides the functionality you seek.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ManuelH, it could have been so great to have the stream source support. I totally agree with you, it is a lot of work to implement this on my own, so I must find the perfect tool for that.